# Postfix pipe always runs as nobody

Tags: postfix, permissions, email-server, unix, www-data

**The problem**

I would like postfix to pipe emails to a script that operates on files owned by the `www-data` group located under `/var/www/`. However, I receive error messages that indicate insufficient privileges. By letting the script run `whoami`, I can confirm it's run by the correct user `scriptuser` (as set in my `/etc/postfix/transport` file). I can also confirm that the user has sufficient access rights, as no errors occur when executing the script using `sudo -u scriptuser /path/to/script`.

Therefore, I am quite confused and a bit lost. How is it possible that the user has access right to the files, the script is run by Postfix as this specific user, but I still get the `permission denied` message?

I have also tried adding `default_privs = www-data` to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`, as suggested in [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/444903/postfix-wont-pipe-to-php-file-through-aliases-file) with no success. Enabling access via `chmod o+rx` does the job, but I would consider this potentially dangerous as anyone with shell access to the server could read those files.

**The config files**

```
# in file /etc/postfix/main.cf
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
virtual_maps  = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual/addresses

# in file /etc/postfix/master.cf
mailreply   unix    -   n   n   -   -   pipe
  flags=FR user=scriptuser argv=/usr/lib/postfix/sbin/pipemailreply

# in file /etc/postfix/transport
mailreplyuser@localhost mailreply

# in file /etc/postfix/virtual/addresses
mydomain.com                     DOMAIN
@mydomain.com                    mailreplyuser@localhost
```

The file rights in `/var/www/hmtl/` (via `ls -la`):

```
drwxrws--- 4 www-data www-data  4096 Mar 13 00:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root      4096 Mar 13 01:02 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     www-data     8 Mar 13 00:15 test.txt
```

**The error message**

```
Mar 13 10:13:21 myservername postfix/pipe[3545]: 774F3FEB3B: to=<mailreplyuser@localhost>, orig_to=<test@mydomain.com>, relay=mailreply, delay=0.13, delays=0.07/0/0/0.06, dsn=5.3.0, status=bounced (Command died with status 1: "/usr/lib/postfix/sbin/pipemailreply". Command output: cat: /var/www/html/test.txt: Permission denied )
```

Comment: It seems that scriptuser doesn't have sufficient permissions to folder /var/www/hmtl/. You can check with ```su -l scriptuser -s /bin/bash -c 'cd /var/www/hmtl/ && cat test.txt'```

Comment: This works absolutely fine, and doesn't give me any errors. The user does have the permission to access the folder / the file when I run it directly via `su -l` or `sudo -u`. It's only when postfix runs the script that the user seemingly stops having the correct access rights.

Answer (score 1):

I changed "user=scriptuser" to "user=scriptuser:scriptgroup" and I was able to make it work.

http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html

Comment: How does that relate to the question?